# Does FFMPEG video in php over shell_exec()

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I have

```
<?
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -start_number 174 -i timelapse/20/%01d.jpg -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -r 24 timelapse/test.webm 2> timelapse/out.txt");
?>
```

I would like to create WebM video (timelapse) from the image of a webcam. Unfortunately I was unable to create a video in PHP5.

`ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-start_number'`

If I remove `-start_number`I receive another error:

`timelapse / 20 /% 01d.jpg: I / O error occured Usually That Means That input file is truncated and / or corrupted.`

I saved as pictures 174.jpg 175.jpg .. and more.

Comment: this isn't a php problem. this is purely ffmpeg.

Comment: %01d means 1 charter file names. 174.jpg is 3 chars.

Answer (score 0):

On local PC is command OK, but if you run the command on the server, I get the error: ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-start_number' AND timelapse / 20 /% 01d.jpg: I / O error occured Usually That Means That input file is truncated and / or corrupted.

On the Internet I found even this command:

```
ffmpeg -i timelapse/20/{174..1204}.jpg -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -r 24 timelapse/test.webm
```

This statement was slightly better, but again with an error.

```
FFmpeg version r11872+debian_0.svn20080206-18+lenny3, Copyright (c) 2000-2008 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaad --enable-pp --enable-swscaler --enable-x11grab --prefix=/usr --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --disable-strip --enable-libdc1394 --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-altivec --disable-vis --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil version: 49.6.0
  libavcodec version: 51.50.0
  libavformat version: 52.7.0
  libavdevice version: 52.0.0
  built on Feb 13 2011 03:56:05, gcc: 4.3.2
Input #0, image2, from 'timelapse/20/174.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.0, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 740x555 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25.00 tb(r)
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'timelapse/20/175.jpg'
```